# Magento2: Redirect to dashboard menu in admin panel?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, admin-panel, custom-menu

I have created the custom menu in the admin panel. When I click on menu option then redirect to dashboard.

My Magento v2.0.17

**Menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Pfay_Contacts" title="Pierre FAY Contacts" module="Pfay_Contacts" sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Pfay_Contacts" resource="Pfay_Contacts::contacts"/>
    <add id="Pfay_Contacts::index" title="Pierre FAY Contacts" module="Pfay_Contacts" action="contacts/test/index" parent="Pfay_Contacts" sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Pfay_Contacts" resource="Pfay_Contacts::contacts"/>
</menu>
```

**Route**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route id="contacts" frontName="contacts">
        <module name="Pfay_Contacts" before="Magento_Backend"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

**Block Page**

```
<?php
namespace Pfay\Contacts\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Contactslist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = array())
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->setData('contacts',array());
}

public function addContacts($count)
{
    $_contacts = $this->getData('contacts');
    $actualNumber = count($_contacts);
    $names = array();
    for($i=$actualNumber;$i<($actualNumber+$count);$i++) {
        $_contacts[] = 'nom '.($i+1);
    }
    $this->setData('contacts',$_contacts);
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace Pfay\Contacts\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
public function execute()
{
    die('test admin view');
}
}
```

Comment: you forget to paste the proper code here or you are missed to add forward slash  \ before **Template\Context $context**  in __construct param?

Comment: Hi @Hit's code is correct. We do not need the forward slash before **Template\Context**

Comment: yes right just checking it, as I don't have enough time to check your code please check here sample module of admin menu https://github.com/hitesh-srtpl/magento225-demo/tree/master/app/code/Srtpl/Backendsample

Comment: Ok...I will check and Update you

Comment: I have checked. It is working fine. Thanks @Hit's

Comment: Please share the link under the post. It is a helpful link to everyone. @Hit's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an admin menu in admin side, then please follow this [link](https://github.com/hitesh-srtpl/magento225-demo/tree/master/app/code/Srtpl/Backendsample)

and later you can compare your code and above module code to check whether you did a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing Acl which manage admin access area permission.

Create `acl.xml` at `app/code/Pfay/Contacts/etc/` and you have to define the ACL for this module URLs.

If you check menu.xml you will find out you have  use resource `resource="Pfay_Contacts::contacts"`
 but does not define the resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <!-- Menu -->
                <resource id="Pfay_Contacts::contacts" title="Pierre FAY Contacts" translate="title" sortOrder="100">
                    <resource id="Pfay_Contacts::index" title="Pierre FAY Contacts" translate="title" sortOrder="101">
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Pfay_Contacts::contacts" title="Pierre FAY Contacts" module="Pfay_Contacts" sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Pfay_Contacts" resource="Pfay_Contacts::contacts"/>
    <add id="Pfay_Contacts::index" title="Pierre FAY Contacts" module="Pfay_Contacts" action="contacts/test/index" parent="Pfay_Contacts" sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Pfay_Contacts" resource="Pfay_Contacts::contacts" parent="Pfay_Contacts::contacts"/>
</menu>
```